# How to perform Swipe left on iOS device using Appium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I would like to perform a Swipe left on a particular xpath using appium. Is there anyway I can do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the above scenario, do the below:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElementByXPath("//ur elem xpath");
int x = elem.getLocation().getX();
int y = elem.getLocation().getY();

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
 action.longPress(x+5,y+5).waitAction(3000).moveTo(100,0).perform().release();
```

let me know what happens

Comment: I am trying to do it for a particular field. Is there any way I can do that using xpath or id

Comment: what kink of field is this? can u please explain ur requirement more elaborately?

Comment: I have updated the above query. I have swipe left at Test 1 field

Comment: it is swiping the whole screen

Comment: ok, i think u need to long press on Test1 manually for swipe, ryt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114105/discussion-between-noor-and-arun-kumar).

Comment: u may increase or decrease 100 according to what happen in ur screen

Answer (score 0):

@noor This worked for me

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        swipeObject.put("startX", 279.2);
        swipeObject.put("startY", 93.1);
        swipeObject.put("endX", 136.1);
        swipeObject.put("endY", 92.6);
        swipeObject.put("duration", 3.0);
        js.executeScript("mobile: flick", swipeObject);
```